# Is there a way to have somewhat globally persistent marks?

Tags: neovim, mark

Basically, I like marks.

I'd like to save/keep my marks either in the file, or as a project configuration, is there an extension or a way to do so?

I know that the project or file based settings are frowned upon, so I should mention this is for my own personal projects only.

Comment: Have you tried uppercase marks? `mA` and `'A`  are persistent between two restarts of Vim. The difference with lowercase marks is that the uppercases marks are shared between files (so if you set `mA` on file1 and then `mA` on file2  you will lose the mark on file1)

Comment: See `:help mksession` and `:help viminfo`